# Force light mode in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Since yesterday google chrome have been running in dark mode. As far as I understand, this is due to a new update which makes chrome follow the mode of my default app mode. When I google for an answer most of the questions is about how to **enable** dark mode, but not many about how to **disable** it or force light mode.

I'm running on windows 10 with dark mode as default app mode and **I intend to continue doing so**, so changing to light theme isn't the solution here. I have tried changing the theme on chrome but the url bar is still in black so that would be the last solution.

I've seen a number of command line switches on [peter.sh](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but those are intended for chromium, not google chrome (I know that they share many similar switches but they are not completely identical). I saw that there is a `--force-dark-mode` but it seems like there isn't any `--force-light-mode`.

Can I find an updated list of google chrome command line switches somewhere else, or any other solution that might work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should try what you found for Chromium. It's the (open-source) base code for Chrome, the only difference being the latter has some Google proprietary code added. For such basic operations what works in Chromium should work in the same version Chrome.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Hi! I did look through the list some times but couldn't find any switches that gives the desired result. Also this is a single persons website, doesn't google have any documentations covering this? I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 4):

As of the version 76.0.3809.100, this solution **doesn't work anymore**. [(1)](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4877043?msgid=11539069),[(2)](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/cnfjdo/cant_disable_dark_mode_after_latest_update/)

---

I took a look at this issue in Google Support and found [this answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4877043?msgid=5321120):

> Add to Chrome shortcut properties target: `--disable-features=DarkMode`
>
> So the entire target looks something like:
> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=DarkMode`

Do this to your desktop shortcut (and unpin/repin the icon in the taskbar to get the updated shortcut) and it should be light while Windows is still in Dark Mode.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I had some issues with it not starting correctly due to me starting chrome from taskbar. Just unpinned and repinned it and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @kebbaben Nice, glad it worked!

Comment: It seems that google have once again changed something for the worse and now the command line switch doesn't work since this morning. Do you have any other ideas of how to to fix this problem?

Comment: @kebbaben hey, it appears it's not [only you](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4877043?msgid=5321120&). I'll have a look again and I come up with something I will edit the answer

Comment: Then as this doesn't work anymore I'll have to revoke the accepted answer until a new one has been provided.

Comment: @kebbaben sure, as I said, something changed and on that same thread people are reporting it's not working either. Also on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/cnfjdo/cant_disable_dark_mode_after_latest_update/)

Comment: Hey, I found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/cnvxwl/i_cant_disable_dark_mode_on_google_chrome/ewf3f6u/) you probably need to downgrade to get the light mode as there is no solution for the latest version.

Comment: While it's true that, that is a currently working solution. It's a solution that won't last for long, as it tell you to downgrade version and disable the possibility to update chrome. While that stops google to make bad _improvements_, you still lose important things like security updates.

Comment: That's why is in the comments and not in a answer because downgrading compromises updates, etc. We'll wait for Google position and I'll keep this answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

In the Chrome address bar enter the following:

chrome://flags#enable-force-dark

Then, for the option ensure that option "Disabled" is selected. After the change your browser will ask you if you want to restart - do so.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I've found no real solutions but a few workarounds that I will put here for reference.

## Set *default app mode* to "light"

The workaround I'm currently using is setting the *default app mode* to light. It's exactly what I don't want to do in order to fix this, but it's my best choice for now.

---

## Download a Google Chrome theme

If you still want to have the *default app mode* set to dark, you can install a [white theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pure-white-theme/kddbloafkgmgpoakpledogpkdcnajogm?hl=en) to google chrome. This isn't really the best workaround. While it does give you a light mode chrome it also leaves your URL field completely dark.

---

## Use a different web browser

This isn't really a workaround but choosing a different browser might relieve you from the fear of Google's scary whims. As I said "This isn't really a workaround" but sometimes many problems can be solved by switching browsers.

---

## Use the `--disable-features=DarkMode` switch

Possibly the worst workaround is reverting to chrome to any version prior to version 76.0.3809.100, disable auto-updating and adding `--disable-features=DarkMode` to the shortcut used when starting chrome.

The **target** string should look like this `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=DarkMode`. Of course the path itself will be different if you've installed chrome elsewhere.

The reason why this is possibly the worst workaround is because it not only leaves you without newer updates to chrome, but it's also a big **security risk**. Google actively push out security updates to their browser and without them you're more vulnerable to malicious attacks.

---

I won't mark this as answer as it doesn't propose a solution yet. I will add more workarounds (and hopefully a solution) here as I come across them.

Comment: That white theme did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if newer versions of Chrome have addressed this problem.
They have provided a light / dark theme toggle bar on the Google Home page | Settings in the page footer.

I got this solution to much relief from

https://www.alphr.com/turn-off-dark-mode-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome added a new feature in the customization settings recently. Change color mode to white and you can keep your windows settings to default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by going to Go to windows setting > colors > Custom and then I chose Dark for default Windows and Light for Windows App.

Comment: Read the question before posting an answer. In my question I wrote: _I'm running on windows 10 with dark mode as default app mode **and I intend to continue doing so**_. Even if it solves your problem, this answer is not a solution to **this problem**.

Answer (score -4):

I have same problem as well.

It's about your windows setting. Go to windows setting > colors > choose your default app mode to "light", then go back to chrome, it should change back to the original light mode.

But of course it means your windows can't have dark background of course.
For your reference, now I choose to stay in dark for windows setting, and change the chrome theme to "pro grey', it a compromise for me.

[change the setting from dark to light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfBD2.png)

Comment: this doesn't answer the question in any way

Comment: @lee Please read the question before answering: "I'm running on windows 10 with dark mode as default app mode and I intend to continue doing so"