# How to force light mode when Chrome opening links from 3rd parties applications

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I am using Chrome in Windows 10 and disabled dark mode with appending `--disable-features=DarkMode` to the shortcut.

This workaround is working (as it is described here: [Force light mode in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1430098/force-light-mode-in-google-chrome)).

But it is still running in a dark mode when I'm opening link `http` or `https`, for example, from email: when I'm clicking a link Chrome is launching (as it is default browser) in a dark mode. It happens when Chrome launching in a new window. In a case when Chrome was opened: a new tab from external link runs in a light mode.

How to force light mode when Chrome opening links from 3rd parties applications?

Comment: Sorry, `--disable-features=DarkMode` is not working on the latest version of Chrome. [Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/4877043?msgid=11539069), Superuser [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1430098/force-light-mode-in-google-chrome/)

Comment: It is still working with Chrome 75. And my question is about how to force white theme (light mode) during opening links from email application

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now, thanks for the clarification and yes, Chrome 75 is still working fine with that flag

Comment: @CaldeiraG Dear friend, this idea  is working. Thank you very much!