# After switching to Windows 10 dark mode, Chrome now looks exactly the same in incognito and standard mode

Tags: google-chrome

I switched chrome to dark mode in Win10, and it is easier on my eyes - I like it.

My only beef is, that now it is very difficult to distinguish between incognito mode and the regular mode in Google Chrome.

Ideally, I would want a completely different theme for incognito (something bright red or whatever makes it clear).

**What can be done to make it visually very clear which mode I am in?**

[image]

Chrome version: Version 77.0.3865.120 (Official Build) (64-bit) @ Windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force light mode in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1430098/force-light-mode-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Up until Chrome version 75 it was [apparently possible](https://techdows.com/2019/05/disable-dark-mode-in-google-chrome-only-but-not-for-windows-10.html#comment-189977) to disable dark mode in Chrome only by appending

`--disable-features=DarkMode`

to the target field of the Chrome shortcut.

I've tried various suggested solutions including installing Chrome themes (but these affect both normal and incognito mode so doesn't resolve the issue of easily distinguishing between them). For now I've come to the conclusion that there isn't currently an easy solution to this issue.

Will keep a lookout and report back here if I find anything.